# Parsing HTML: lxml error in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I am writing a simple script to fetch the big grey table from [here](http://www.afi.com/100years/movies10.aspx).

The code I have is the following:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.afi.com/100years/movies10.aspx").read()

root = etree.XML(html)
```

But I am getting an error on the last statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Workspace\afi100\afi100.py", line 13, in <module>
    root = etree.XML(html)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2720, in lxml.etree.XML (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52577)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1556, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79602)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1435, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78449)
  File "parser.pxi", line 943, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75099)
  File "parser.pxi", line 547, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71467)
  File "parser.pxi", line 628, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72340)
  File "parser.pxi", line 568, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71683)
XMLSyntaxError: Space required after the Public Identifier, line 3, column 59
```

Any idea how can I get around this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You think it is a good idea to parse HTML using an XML parser?

Comment: You should any available HTML to XML (xhtml) tool.

Comment: I was under the false impression that HTML was a subset of XML (it's not, but XHTML is). There's a good description of the major differences at http://techforum4u.com/content.php/318-What-is-the-difference-between-HTML-and-XML

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to parse HTML with the XML parser, you should use the lxml HTML parser.

```
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

ufile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.afi.com/100years/movies10.aspx")

root = etree.parse(ufile, etree.HTMLParser())

print etree.tostring(root)
```

Comment: Interesting, is that a true HTML parser or does it only set `libxml2`'s recovery flag?

Answer (score 1):

The document you link to is not well-formed XHTML, therefore you can't use an XML parser to load it.

You have to use an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: Thansk for the reply. Would libxml2dom work instead? I have used it before.

Comment: @nunos, probably not, since it's a binding to the `libxml2` library which, to my knowledge, only reliably supports well-formed XML.

Comment: whilst you can use Beautiful Soup, lxml can also handle HTML (see koblas' accepted answer).