# Python: Parsing XML with lxml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to use a library called [dblp-python](https://github.com/scholrly/dblp-python). This library parses the DBLP data (which is in XML format). While I am trying to print all publications of an author, the script acts weirdly. Sometimes it prints them without any errors, and sometimes it shows an error. If I run the same code more than once after an error, it shows the publications without any problem. 
The code I use is:

```
a = dblp.search('Michael L. Littman')
for i in range(len(a[0].publications)):
    print i
    print a[0].publications[i].title
```

The error I get when I execute the above code is:

```
> Traceback (mostrecent call last):   File "<pyshell#217>", line 3, in <module>
>     print a[0].publications[i].title   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dblp\__init__.py", line 19, in __getattr__
>     self.load_data()   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dblp\__init__.py", line 110, in load_data
>     root = etree.fromstring(xml)   File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3092, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:70691)   File
> "parser.pxi", line 1828, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
> (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106689)   File "parser.pxi", line 1716, in
> lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105478)   File
> "parser.pxi", line 1086, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
> (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100105)   File "parser.pxi", line 580, in
> lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
> (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94543)   File "parser.pxi", line 690, in
> lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:96003)   File
> "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
> (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:95050) XMLSyntaxError: Space required after the
> Public Identifier, line 2, column 47
```

The code of the library can be seen [HERE](https://github.com/scholrly/dblp-python/blob/master/dblp/__init__.py).
I raised this problem to the author but without response. I hope of anyone can help me here at least to know what the error might be.
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a memory related issue. When it returns successfully you may have more memory and on the times it fails, you might have less. Whats the size of the file you are searching? On a separate note, should you be using xpath for this?

Comment: The dblp dataset is very large (>1GB). However, it seems from the code that it queries the dblp website and does not load the whole xml document for dblp (loads xml that answers the query only). For xpath, I thought this code will save my time.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Would of been great to have an answer here! :(

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371004/parsing-html-lxml-error-in-python